# Python3 - When exactly do you need to prepend "self._" to variable declarations within class methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry, this is a really basic question, but I am just wondering when it is necessary to prepend `self._` to variable declarations within methods? Every time I declare a variable within a method should I declare it with `self._` included? Is there any situation where I should not do this?

Which of these methods would be valid for example (for some hypothetical class):

```
def thing_counter(self, thing):
    length_of_thing = len(thing)
    return length_of_thing
```

OR

```
def thing_counter(self, thing):
    self._length_of_thing = len(thing)
    return self._length_of_thing
```

Both work, but which would be strictly correct?

I know that a variable declaration is not really needed here, I am just trying to use a simple example.

Cheers!

Answer (score 17):

Both work equally.

In the first version, `length_of_thing` will be created inside the function, and the `return` will return a copy to the caller. `length_of_thing` itself will not exist anymore after the return.

In the second one, `self._length_of_thing` will be created, not inside the function, but inside the instance of the class. The result is that it will be visible to all other methods. And the `return` still returns a copy.
So possibly this version uses a little more memory, as the variable `self._length_of_thing` remains alive till the instance of the class is destroyed.